# How to mock Eureka when doing Integration Tests in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-test, spring-test-mvc, netflix-eureka

I am running a simple Junit Testing a Controller in Spring Boot. The test code looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {FrontControllerApplication.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@IntegrationTest({"server.port:0", "eureka.client.registerWithEureka:false", "eureka.client.fetchRegistry:false"})
@ActiveProfiles("integrationTest")
public class MyControllerIT {
```

In the application-integrationTest.properties I have the following Eureka Settings:

```
####### Eureka
eureka.serviceUrl.default=http://localhost:8767/eureka/
eureka.printDeltaFullDiff=false
eureka.client.refresh.interval=1
eureka.appinfo.replicate.interval=1
eureka.serviceUrlPollIntervalMs=1000
eureka.name=${spring.application.name}

####### Netflix Eureka #######
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8767/eureka/
eureka.client.instanceInfoReplicationIntervalSeconds=1
eureka.client.initialInstanceInfoReplicationIntervalSeconds=0
eureka.instance.virtualHostName=${spring.application.name}
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.instance.initialStatus=DOWN
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=3
eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds=10
eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
eureka.eurekaserver.connectionIdleTimeoutInSeconds=5
eureka.responseCacheAutoExpirationInSeconds=5
```

when a junit test started I see the following:

`2015-09-16 16:46:03,905 ERROR localhost-startStop-1 com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient                   Can't get a response from http://localhost:8767/eureka/apps/
Can't contact any eureka nodes - possibly a security group issue? 
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:184) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.11.jar:1.11]`

**The test passes, that is not the problem**, but I see a lot of exception stack traces that has to do with Eureka. The questions is if there is a way to mock eureka or another way to skip brining it up when doing tests?

The benefit would be easier to see relevant stack traces if test would fail and tst would run much faster

Answer (score 27):

Another solution is to disable the Eureka Client in your application.properties or application.yml file under test/resources

applications.properties:

`eureka.client.enabled=false`

application.yml:

`eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false`

This has the benefit of not needing to remeber to include the system property for every JUnit test that requires disabling the Eureka Client.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. Perfect for lazy and smart developers.

Comment: Thanks Victor, I appreciate it!

Comment: If running spring with profiles, put this in application-test.yml, then annotate your test @ActiveProfiles("test")

Answer (score 13):

You can set a system property for `eureka.client.enabled=false` for tests.

If you're running the tests using gradle you can do this:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperty 'eureka.client.enabled', 'false'
}
```

If you're running tests in an IDE then you'll have to set the system property there as well.

Comment: Nice. This solved my problem. This annotation prevents registration with eureka from Integration tests `@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port:0", "eureka.client.enabled:false"})`

Comment: Of course, as of now, this is `@SpringBootTest({"server.port:0", "eureka.client.enabled:false"})`

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` is available starting with Spring Boot 1.4.0.M2