# Override single entry in application.yml for all tests

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

Within the SpringBoot application you can provide the configuration via `src/main/resource/application.yml`.

One single entry should be overriden by the tests (see [How to mock Eureka when doing Integration Tests in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769556/846163) ). I tried to provide a test configuration with `src/integration-test/resource/application.yml` but it overrides the complete configuration.

```
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false
```

How can I modify one entry of the configuration file for all tests?

Comment: just start your tests with `-Deureka.client.enabled=false` (VM arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `application-test.yml` in `src/main/resource/` with your desired configuration `(eureka.client.enabled=false)` and also other configurations that you require for your application to start up,

Once your `application-test.yml` is complete You just need to add following annotation with desired value to your test class ,

`@SpringBootTest(value={"spring.profiles.active=test"})`

Here `spring.profiles.active=test` because we have set its value to `test` because we want to read configurations from `application-test.yml`.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer a solution without changing every test class.